# Ways to connect mongodb to grafana

Tags: mongodb, time-series, real-time, visualization, grafana

My question is different ways to connect `mongodb` with `grafana`

[Link for reference](https://github.com/percona/mongodb_exporter) ?

Comment: Are looking for a way to monitor MongoDB stats or your MongoDB datas ?

Comment: nope , i need to visualize an time series data in mongo db

Comment: Do you mean connect `mongodb` as a datasource in Grafana? Because the provided link is a kind of node-exporter for Prometheus. In this case the datasource is `Prometheus` not `mongodb`...

Comment: yes i need to connect the mongodb as data source for grafana . Right we are connecting mongo through simple json plugin but its creating redundancy and processing is slow

Answer (score 7):

Try using [MongoDB datasource for Grafana](https://github.com/JamesOsgood/mongodb-grafana)

It should allow you to hook up your MongoDB data source just fine...

[image]
[Source](https://github.com/JamesOsgood/mongodb-grafana/raw/master/src/img/sample_datasource.png)

Answer (score 4):

Right now grafana doesn't support MongoDB as a data source [Using mongoDB as back-end repository](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/1112)

But they offer a workaround [grafana simple json data source](https://grafana.net/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource)

Comment: Yes ,i have used second option.
we have tweaked the plugin code.
we retrieve data from mongodb and pass it as json format to simplejson .

Answer (score 2):

There's also a new MongoDB data source plugin for paid Grafana:
https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-mongodb-datasource

Comment: Seems like this plugin/feature is only available to users with the "Grafana enterprise" subscription: "You need a Grafana subscription before you can install this enterprise plugin." (At the time of writing there doesn't even seem to be any pricing information on their site.)

Comment: The pricing for Grafana enterprise is around 45000$/year. If you negotiate, you can get plugin only offer for 10000$/year.

Comment: The Grafana MongoDB plugin is now available to Grafana Cloud customers as an add-on for $25/active user per mo: https://grafana.com/pricing/